# Azure AD with spring boot with user in local Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

Helo Here,
I Hope you are doing well.
I's been few days I'm having this problem.

I have a spring boot API using Azure AD authentication thanks to `AADResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Here is the flow I want to have:

1. User gets token from Azure in the react native frontend (done)
2. User logs into the api thanks to the given token. (to-do)
3. If user doesn't exists in local db, then it's created thanks to info from the token.

Here is my question:
**How can I do to be able to have a callback / function executed when the user first connect to the api with a new token ?** With this answer, I will be able to check if an user exist with the provided email in the token, and create it if it's not existing.

Here is my websecurity config:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AADOAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfig extends AADResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs"
    };


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("*").permitAll();
       http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
//       super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

I know this is messy because it is stil a part in development, but I would like to complete it thank  to your information.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Did you mean that you need a function to decode the token and get the email contained in the token? If so, you can use [this library](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that you've done the step of getting access token. So I think you can add a filter to judge if the user contained in the token exists in your database. Here's a sample filter.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.Claim;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

//@Component
@WebFilter(filterName = "JwtRequestFilter", urlPatterns = {"/helloworld/*"})
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(jwtToken);
                //set the claim name in the parameter to obtain email address
                String email = jwt.getClaim("unique_name").asString();
                //use email address to check if it exists in database
                Date expiresAt = jwt.getExpiresAt();
                if(expiresAt.before(new Date())) {
                    Map<String, Object> errRes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    Map<String, Object> errMesg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    errMesg.put("code", "InvalidAuthenticationToken");
                    errMesg.put("message", "Access token has expired.");
                    errRes.put("error", errMesg);
                    String json = JSONObject.toJSONString(errRes);   
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, json);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (JWTDecodeException exception){
                System.out.println("Unable to Decode the JWT Token");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank-you! Do you think it would be appropriate to keep an in-memory Set of token already checked to avoid unecessary db requests ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a good idea. In my position, if there're many users and requests, it will then save many token in the memory, and we need to check if the saved token is expired(access token will be expired 1 hour later by default, and the expired policy can be changed, expire time maybe less).